# SQL ROUND() function issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried to use `round` function to convert for example `348.426580` to `348.43`
But in below query I used the result I got is `348.430000` in `[ShippingCost]` column

How can I omit the four zeros?

```
SELECT  S.Product_Name, 
        SPD.UnitPrice, 
        SPD.Quantity, 
        SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice Amount,
        CONVERT(INT,(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)/(SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER()) * 100) [Cost %],
        ROUND((SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)/(SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER()) * Sp.Shipping_Cost,2) [ShippingCost],
        (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)/(SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER()) * Sp.Customs_Cost [CustomsCost],
        (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)/(SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER()) * Sp.Shipping_Cost + (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)/(SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER()) * Sp.Customs_Cost +SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice - SpD.Discount [TotalAmount]
FROM dbo.Stock_Purchase SP
INNER JOIN dbo.Stock_Purchase_Details SPD
    ON SP.Purchase_ID = SPD.Purchase_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Store S
    ON SPD.Pro_ID = S.Pro_ID;
```

Comment: If you are aware of _displayed zeros_ then I'm afraid this is completely non database question. This is UI job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast to a decimal, say `DECIMAL(10, 2)`.  Because casting automatically does rounding, there is no need for `round()`:

```
    CAST((SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)/(SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER()) * Sp.Shipping_Cost as decimal(10, 2)) as [ShippingCost],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ROUND(column_name,decimals)
```

> column_name Required for The field to round.
>
> decimals  Required for Specifies the number of decimals to be returned.

[See](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) this.